# How Do I Search The Same Word In Different TextViews?

Tags: android, search, textview, full-text-search

I have about 50 different textviews in a linear layout in a scrollview

its like this

1.This is the first textview

2.This is the second textview

3.This is the third textview

4.This is the fourth textview

5.This is the fifth textview

6.This is the sixth textview

7.This is the seventh textview

8.This is the eighth textview

9.This is the ninth textview

10.This is the tenth textview

I have an edittext and button for search ,what i want is when i enter a number say 6 in the edittext and click the button then it should show or go to 6.This is the sixth textview,also i dont want other textviews to disappear,i just want the camera to move to textview number 6.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void scrollToView(final ScrollView scrollView, final View view) {
    view.requestFocus();
    final Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
    scrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);
    if (!view.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, view.getBottom());
            }
        });
    } 
}

Button clickButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yout_button_id);
clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String n = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edittext_id)).getText();
                int tn = Integer.parseInt(n); //TODO: check the view exists
                TextView tv = (TextView)((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_linearlayout_id)).getChildAt(tn);
                scrollToView((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.yout_scrollview_id, tv);
            }
        });
```